# Installing iOS Facebook SDK without using CocoaPod

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm following this official documentation to install FB SDK and trying to integrate it with my React Native project: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/ , so that I can show a Facebook share dialog in my app.

However, one of the steps requires to use CocoaPod to get the libraries. My React Native project doesn't work well with CocoaPod, I want to avoid it as much as possible. Is there a way to install the libraries manually without using CocoaPods?

Much appreciated if you can point me to some documentation or tutorials. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the entire iOS SDK (outside of Cocoapods) by going to bottom of this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/componentsdks

There also seems to be a Reactive Native-focused tutorial [found here](https://tylermcginnis.com/installing-the-facebook-sdk-into-a-react-native-android-and-ios-app/), where it looks like you can use `npm install` and `react-native link`.